# "localhost" и "виртуальные хосты" локально

Tags: apache, веб-программирование

Добрый день.

Работаю на маке. Так же тестирую сайты с других компьютеров/телфонов или через виртуальные машины. На рабочем комьютере стоит сбока XAMPP, могу обращаться к сайтам так:

```
localhost/my-site
127.0.0.1/my-site
192.168.13/my-site
```

плюс настроенные виртуальные хосты, инклюд в httpd.conf и строки в файле hosts:

```
my-site.local
ru.my-site.local
```

Однако, с других машин я могу обращаться к своим сайтам только как:

```
192.168.13/my-site
```

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то в рамках локальной сети обратиться к сайту через вирутальный хост? Ну т.е. написать в браузере **ru.my-site.local**, но чтобы сайт при этом открылся с другого компьютера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть следующие варианты:

1. Пропишите `192.168.13 ru.mysite.local` в hosts на каждом компьютере вашей сети, с которого вы хотите иметь доступ к вашему локальному сайту.
2. Откройте доступ к вашему локальному хосту через Dynamic DNS (например, [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/free)).
3. Поднимите в локальной сети свой DNS сервер, который будет резолвить хост `ru.mysite.local` в IP вашего компьютера. Естественно, на каждом компьютере вашей локальной сети в настройках придётся заменить стандартный DNS сервер на ваш.
4. Разворачиаайте ваш тестовый сайт не на своём компьютере, а в облаке.

Я бы порекомендовал использовать второй вариант. Первый требует изменений на нескольких машинах и, если в вашей сети IP адреса раздаются динамически, может сломаться после перезагрузки вашего компьютера или роутера. Третий - расстрел воробьёв из крупнокалиберных пулемётов, и также требует вносить изменения на нескольких машинах. Четвёртый хорош, так как позволяет обкатать вывод сайта в интернет, но он требует больше телодвижений, чем второй.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне так-то нравится первый вариант :)
Адреса компьюетров можно и статичными сделать в локальной сети. Но проблема со смартфонами остается. У них же нету файла hosts... или есть? :)
Попробую второй вариант.

Comment: Как минимум в Android-смартфонах hosts есть, но он доступен только на рутованых устройствах. Насчёт iPhone сказать не могу.

Comment: 3 хорош, на роутерах иногда (в основном на перепрошитых) встречается DNS-кэшилка, выдаваемая по DHCP.

Comment: Это если локальная сеть - в пределах кавртиры, и все устройства подключаются к одному роутеру. А если это локалка, объединяющая несколько квартир или офисов, то перепрошитым роутером проблема не решается.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Надо только на том устройстве с которого идет обращение тоже прописать в **hosts**

```
192.168.13 ru.my-site.local
```

Если устройств много, или не на всех возможно редактировать **hosts** то возможен вариант с настройкой своего ДНС сервера. А на устройствах прописать его адрес как дополнительный ДНС.

Если речь идет о локальной сети, то вероятней всего это можно сделать на роутере и тогда может быть даже не надо будет менять настройки сети на устройствах.